# How to check if SD card inserted in Android?

Tags: android, storage, android-sdcard

I want to check if the phone has SD card inserted or not.
Actually I want to provide user to select the storage location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has several duplicates, however, you can check for the SD card like this:

```
Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
```

Comment: Please do not answer a question that has dup. This might just be closed later on. Thankyou